# Touchscreen Performance (iPhone, iPad, Android, Nexus S, etc.)

Tags: iphone, android, touchscreen

Who makes the touch screens for the iPhone or Android devices? Specifically I'm wondering what the sampling rate is for dragging, etc. that gives these devices such smooth touch and drag performance.

Also is there a common standard of measurement for touch screen performance? How do you quantify a touch screens drag performance?

Comment: I would add that the sampling rate (sub 10 Hz) may be low as the software could be using interpolation.

Comment: @Thomas - The software is almost certainly doing a lot of work; the question is how low the sampling rate actually is.

Comment: Does Apple's documentation cover anything about how fast drag events are captured and your respective selector (i.e. handler) is hit? I can't find anything. I figure it has to be in the 20ms range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All but the cheapest phones and tablets are using capacitive sensors rather than resistive ones.

But I think a lot of the user experience is not with the touch screen itself, but rather with the graphics engine and the software stack driving it.  For example, a first generation android phone like the G1 is probably a faster processor than the first generation iphone was, but flipping through an image gallery on the original iphone was much smoother because they put a lot more thought into engineering a system where that could be done efficiently.

Answer (score 4):

Atmel is selling lots of their [maXTouch](http://www.atmel.com/products/touchscreens/default.asp?family_id=701&source=home) devices for touch screen implementations. I don't think that Apple uses them, though. You should get some idea of the performance achievable from the data sheets. They take a lot of the load off the processor, given that they have stuff like gesture recognition built-in.

Answer (score 1):

Travis, sampling rate is important, but the other things are important too. Thats the really answer about the great experience on iDevices. The full sum is well balanced: touchscreen tech  (for sensitiviy) + controller inteface (sampling rate and signal integrity for multitouch) + GPU (for smooth scrolling hardware acceleration) + tuned firmware tighly coupled.  You can check the products that Cypress or ATMEL offer to get more info about the challenges on build touchscreens controllers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a report in Apple's iOS developer forum that the iPhone touchscreen is capable of a maximum of a 60 Hz position sampling or reporting rate, as the touchscreen sensor driver is synced to the display refresh rate.